# In a <paper-dropdown-menu>, use a <paper-menu> or <paper-listbox>? Difference?

Tags: polymer

A simple material design dropdown can be created like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-menu class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>First Option</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Second Option</paper-item>
  </paper-menu>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

or like this:

```
<paper-dropdown-menu>
  <paper-listbox class="dropdown-content">
    <paper-item>First Option</paper-item>
    <paper-item>Second Option</paper-item>
  </paper-listbox>
</paper-dropdown-menu>
```

Both look the same, what's the difference? When do you use which one?

Comment: paper-listbox is an "alias" for paper-menu they actually are implemented the same except listbox has a undocumented property hostAttributes. So you can use whatever suits you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When it comes to Polymer 2.0, you'd notice that

`<paper-menu>` is deprecated in favour of `<paper-listbox>`.
https://github.com/PolymerElements/paper-menu#paper-menu